# Capistrano v3 task fails to start unicorn server with error "eval: bundle not found"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, unicorn, capistrano3

I'm using Capistrano v3 to deploy a rails 4 app to a VPS using unicorn with nginx.

Following the [capistrano](http://capistranorb.com) most recent official documentation, I managed to set up everything related to the deployment itself:

I use the gems 'capistrano', 'capistrano-bundler', 'capistrano-rails' and 'capistrano-rvm' and when I do `cap production deploy` everything seems to work without any error message (the repository is pulled from github and copied on the server, assets are precompiled and so on).

At this point if I connect to the sever via ssh and type `/etc/init.d/unicorn start` the server starts as expected, serving my rails app.

However, I created a task to automate this with capistrano v3 that looks like:

```
namespace :unicorn do

  desc 'Start Unicorn'
  task :start do
    on roles(:app) do
      within current_path do
        execute "/etc/init.d/unicorn start"
      end
    end
  end

  desc 'Stop Unicorn'
  task :stop do
    on roles(:app) do
      within current_path do
        execute "/etc/init.d/unicorn stop"
      end
    end
  end

end
```

But whenever I try `capistrano deploy unicorn:start` I get the following error:

```
/etc/init.d/unicorn: 1: eval: bundle: not found
cap aborted!
/etc/init.d/unicorn start stdout: Nothing written
/etc/init.d/unicorn start stderr: Nothing written
```

What's even stranger is that when I start unicorn manually and then do `cap production unicorn:stop` it works seamlessly.

I suspected some differences in available environment variables when logging in via ssh so I configured 'rvm_bin_path', 'path' and 'gem_path' to be the same as on server but I still get the same error.

I'm running out of ideas, anyone knows what could cause this?

Cheers.

Comment: did u figure this out?

Comment: I did not, but I started from scratch using https://github.com/TalkingQuickly/capistrano-3-rails-template and it somehow ended up working.

Answer (score 0):

When rvm is used on the deploy server [rvm1-capistrano3](https://github.com/rvm/rvm1-capistrano3) saves you. You can use [this](https://github.com/vkdimitrov/rvm1cap3) template as how-to